# How come the macro is used as a function, but is not implemented anywhere?

Tags: mysql

The following code is in MySQL 5.5 storage/example/ha_example.cc:

```
MYSQL_READ_ROW_START(table_share->db.str, table_share->table_name.str, TRUE);
rc= HA_ERR_END_OF_FILE;
MYSQL_READ_ROW_DONE(rc);
```

I search the MYSQL_READ_ROW_START definition in the whole project, and find it in the include/probes_mysql_nodtrace.h:

```
#define MYSQL_READ_ROW_START(arg0, arg1, arg2)
#define MYSQL_READ_ROW_START_ENABLED() (0)
#define MYSQL_READ_ROW_DONE(arg0)
#define MYSQL_READ_ROW_DONE_ENABLED() (0)
```

It is just an empty macro definition here.

My question is, How came this macro MYSQL_READ_ROW_START is not associate with any function, but used as a function in the above code?

Thanks.

Comment: The "probes" in the header name suggests that it is something to do with profiling/monitoring/testing/...

Comment: So it means MYSQL_READ_ROW_START(table_share->db.str, table_share->table_name.str, TRUE); does not do anything itself?

Comment: I'm guessing that it is a stub and somewhere there are versions of those macros that do something useful.

Comment: Yes @mu, that it’s found in a file ending with `.h`, so typically a header file, supports that theory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These aren't traditional macros:  they're probe points for DTrace,
an observability framework for Solaris, OS X, FreeBSD and various
other operating systems.

DTrace revolves around the notion that different *providers* offer
certain *probes* at which one can observe running executables or
even the operating system itself.  Some providers are time-based;
by firing at regular intervals the probes can, for example, be
used to profile the use of a CPU.  Other providers are code-based,
and their probes might, for example, fire at the entrance to and
exit from functions.

The code you highlight is an example of the USDT (User-land
Statically Defined Tracing) provider.  The canonical use of the
USDT provider is to expose meaningful events within transactions.
For example, the beginning and end of a transaction might well
occur somewhere deep within different functions;  in this case
it's best for the developer to identify exactly what he wants to
reveal and when.

A USDT probe is more than a switchable printf() although it can
of course be used to reveal information, e.g. some local value
such as the intermediate result of a transaction.  A USDT probe
can also be used to trigger behaviour.  For example, one might
want to activate some network probes for only the duration of a
certain transaction.

Returning to your question, USDT probes are implemented by writing
macros in the code that correspond to a description of the
provider in a ".d" file elsewhere.  This is parsed by the
dtrace(1) utility, which generates a header file that is suitable
for compilation.  On a system that lacks DTrace it would make
sense to define a header file in which the USDT macros became null
ops, and judging by the given filename (probes_mysql_nodtrace.h)
this is what you are observing.

Answer (score 1):

See http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/getting_started_dtrace_saha.html.

To quote:

> DTrace probes are implemented by kernel modules called providers, each
>   of which performs a particular kind of instrumentation to create
>   probes. Providers can thus described as publishers of probes that can
>   be consumed by DTrace consumers (see below). Providers can be used for
>   instrumenting kernel and user-level code. For user-level code, there
>   are two ways in which probes can be defined- User-Level Statically
>   Defined Tracing (USDT) or PID provider.

So it appears to be up to DTrace providers to implement such a macro.